# The resource could not be resolved - wrong warning?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml, data-binding, resources

Visual Studio shows a lot of warnings before the code is compiled like:

Original:

> Die Ressource "ndt_blabla.png" konnte nicht aufgelöst werden.

In English:

> The resource could not be resolved.

The "wrong" lines are underlined. The compilation don't shows some extra exceptions.

Everything, also the the bindings to the resources, works fine.

Is this a fault of VS or can someone explain to me this phenomenon?

Comment: are you talking about c# or wpf ?

Comment: Make sure the `Build Action` on your resource is set to `Resource`.

Comment: This is from the XAML code

Comment: @xs6 Please could you edit your question to be a little more specific. Are these compilation warnings, or exception errors that you get when running the app. If they are compilation warnings Visual Studio should indicate the files and line numbers that are causing the issue.

Comment: @xs6 Thanks for improving your question. This appears to be a compilation error. Please could you post the _full text_ of _one of_ the error messages you are seeing, and the related line(s) of C# or XAML code that the error refers to. Without this extra information it will be difficult to diagnose your problem.

Comment: AH! After I opened the code (clicked right in the xaml code -> open code) the warnings are disappeared. It looks like a Visual Studio fault. Unfortunately, I have no authority to publish the source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After opening the Sourcecode (C#) the warnings disappeared. It looks like a Visual Studio problem.